# Accessing query string variable in the sql query in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, mysql, gridview

I am quite new to asp.net,I am building an application where I need to show the in the grid view,Now the query I am generating for fetching the data from database containing one parameter which comes from the query string.I am using this code

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="MySQLData"
    ConnectionString="server=localhost;port=3309; User Id=xxxxx;password=xxxxx;database=xxxxx"
    ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    SelectCommand="SELECT contenthead.lastmodifieddate,contenthead.heading,lk_technology.technology FROM contenthead JOIN lk_technology WHERE contenthead.techID=lk_technology.techID AND contenthead.authorid='<%=Request.QueryString["uid"]%>'" />
```

Now when I am using <%..%> tag I am getting parser error that says: **Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.**

Now I want to use this variable from query string.Please tell me how I can access this variable in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="..."  ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT [UserId], [LastUpdatedDate] FROM [vw_aspnet_Profiles] WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:QueryString ParameterDefaultValue="0" Name="UserId" QueryStringField="Id" Type="Object"/>
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**You have to add a parameter to your SqlDataSource**

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but I am getting this error,please see this url :http://bugnull.hinduyuvamanch.com/edit_home.aspx?uid=1  (This is my testing server.)

Comment: please give space between asp:QueryStringParameter and DefaultValue and other properties of asp:QueryStringParameter